# How to change values of few properties from one list to another using LINQ C#:

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have two list like

```
List<Customer> customer = new List<Customer>() 
 { Id =1 , Name = 'Demo1' , OrderId = 123}
 { Id =1 , Name = 'Demo2' , OrderId = 123}

List<Order> order = new List<Order>() 
{ Id =77 , CustomerName = 'Demo1'}
{ Id =88 , CustomerName = 'Demo2'}
```

I want to replace `customer.OrderId = order.Id where order.CustomerName = customer.Name`

I want to replace  `customer list OrderId value from order list when CustomerName is matching with Name prop`

I was trying something like this -

```
customer = order.Select(eo => new Customer { Name = eo.CustomerName });
```

this is not correct LINQ can anyone correct me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ is primarily suited for querying, not data modification.

Instead, I would just use simple `foreach`:

```
foreach (var c in customer)
{
    var o = order.FirstOrDefault(o => o.CustomerName == c.Name);
    c.OrderId = o?.Id ?? 0;
}
```

Of course this approach will not work as well when there are multiple orders per customer. Also I would advise to rename the variables to plural - `customers` and `orders` to better denote their meaning.

For a purely LINQ approach, you could write a `ForEach` LINQ extension method, but I find an explicit `foreach` a more readable solution.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is primarily used for querying. You can make a new list that matches your requirements.

If desired you can assign this new list to your variable customers.

You want to join your customers and orders on the name of the customer.

Simple solution:

```
var joinResult = customers.Join(orders,    // join the tables of customers with orders
    customer => customer.Name,             // from every customer take the Name
    order => order.CustomerName,           // from every order take the CustomerName
    (customer, order) => new Customer      // when they match make a new Customer
    {
        Id = customer.Id,                  // take Id and Name from the matching Customer
        Name = customer.Name,
        OrderId = order.Id,                // take the OrderId from the matching order
    })
    .ToList();
customers = joinResult;
```

Alas, this won't work if you have a `Customer` with several `Orders`:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>() 
    { Id = 1 , Name = 'John Doe' , OrderId = 123},

var orders = new List<Order>() 
    { Id =77 , CustomerName = 'John Doe'}
    { Id =88 , CustomerName = 'John Doe'}
```

Should Customer 1 have OrderId 77 or 78?

Are you sure that every Customer has only one Order?

To get a `Customer with all his Orders` use `GroupJoin`

```
var result = customers.GroupJoin(orders, // GroupJoin the customers with orders
    customer => customer.Name,           // from every customer take the Name
    order => order.CustomerName,         // from every order take the CustomerName
    (customer, orders) => new            // for every customer with all his matching orders
    {                                    // make one new object
        Id = customer.Id,                  // take Id and Name from the matching Customer
        Name = customer.Name,

        // TODO Decide what to do if there are several orders for customer with this name
        // Keep all orders? Or keep the oldest one, the newest one?
        // the unpaid ones?
        AllOrders = orders.ToList(),
        OldestOrder = orders.Orderby(order => order.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
        NewestOrder = orders.OrderByDescending(order => order.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
        UnpaidOrders = orders.Where(order => order.Status == Status.Unpaid).ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform a *join* operation (most likely an inner join). LINQ provides such a feature

```
var customerOrders = customer.Join(order,
    c => c.Name,
    o => o.CustomerName,
    (customer, order) =>
    {
        custumer.OrderId= order.Id;
        return customer;
    }).ToList();
```

But as @Martin Zikmund says i'd be carefull with manipulation the data directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through pairs of customer and correspondent orders and update customers for only matched pairs.

```
var matched = customers.Join(orders,
                             customer => customer.Name,
                             order => order.CustomerName,
                             (customer, order) => (Customer: customer, Order: order));

foreach (var pair in matched)
{
    pair.Customer.OrderId = pair.Order.Id;
}
```

Notice that in case when order collection contains more than one order with same customer name, `Join` approach will update customer with order Id occurred last in the collection.

LINQ extension methods designed in "functional" way, where enumerated items handled as immutable. LINQ methods always return new instance of the collection.   Most of the developers will be "very" surprised if items will be mutated during enumeration methods.
So having explicit `foreach` loop will clearly tell other developers of your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join both lists on property `Name` from customer and property `CustomerName` from order and then assign `OrderId` from Order like

```
List<Customer> result = new List<Customer>();

result = (from c in customer
          join o in order on c.Name equals o.CustomerName
          select new Customer
          {
              Id = c.Id,
              Name = c.Name,
              OrderId = o.Id
          }).ToList();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.Id}, \t Name: {item.Name}, \t OrderId: {item.OrderId}");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]